# Excluir un rango de fechas para el valor de un campo en particular

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada facturacion_tiendas con los siguientes campos tienda, fecha_venta, monto_vendido
Las tiendas son tienda01, tienda02, tienda03

Necesito extraer las ventas de un mes  pero que no se tome en cuenta lapso de tiempo cuando se trata de una tienda en particular

Cuando quiero mostrar el monto vendido por todas las tiendas uso la consulta

```
select distinct(tienda) as Tienda, sum(monto_vendido) as monto
from facturacion_tiendas
where fecha_venta between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
group by tienda order by monto desc
```

Si tomara solo una tienda y quiero excluir lo que vendió en un lapso de tiempo determinado, ejemplo entre el 05-07-2017 y el 15-07-2017

uso esta consulta

```
select distinct(tienda) as Tienda, sum(monto_vendido) as monto
from facturacion_tiendas
where fecha_venta between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
and tienda='tienda01'
and fecha_venta not between '2017-07-05' and '2017-07-15'
group by tienda order by monto desc
```

El problema que se presenta es cuando quiero obtener las ventas de todas las tiendas en un período de tiempo con la excepción de lo que vendió la tienda01 en un sub periodo ese periodo

```
select distinct(tienda) as Tienda, sum(monto_vendido) as monto
from facturacion_tiendas
where fecha_venta between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
and (fecha_venta not between '2017-07-05' and '2017-07-15' and tienda='tienda01')
group by tienda order by monto desc
```

este query no me funciona

Trate de hacerlo con case when pero tampoco me funcionó

```
select distinct(tienda) as Tienda, sum(monto_vendido) as monto
from facturacion_tiendas
where fecha_venta between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
and when case tienda=tienda01 then (fecha_venta not between '2017-07-05' and '2017-07-15')
group by tienda order by monto desc
```

Comment: Uhm, en tu último query, donde probaste el `case`, ¿te arroja algún error? Es que tengo la duda porque tengo entendido que el `case` se usa `case when...` y no al revés, como aparece en tu código (`when case...`), o se puede así también?.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when case tienda=tienda01 then (date(fecha_factura) not between'

Comment: Ah pues, dale la vuelta entonces a esa parte, y de paso agrega una condición por defecto, cuando la otra no se cumple: `and case when tienda=tienda01 then (fecha_venta not between '2017-07-05' and '2017-07-15') else 1=1 end case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solución usando la funcion NOT en mysql

```
select distinct(tienda) as Tienda, sum(monto_vendido) as monto
from facturacion_tiendas
where fecha_venta between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
and NOT(tienda='tienda01' and fecha_venta between '2017-07-05' and '2017-07-15')
group by tienda order by monto desc
```

Ahora si me funciona